# redis get key which is another key's value

Tags: get, redis, key

I want to use redis to get value by key ,but the key is another key's value.like:

```
set name "david"
set david femal
```

i get david from the key->name,and the value as the second  object's key,like

```
get (get name)
```

i hope the result is "femal",
  how should i do?besides java client can support it .

Comment: Use a LUA script: http://redis.io/commands/eval